# Assembly AT&T x86 read from file

Tags: c, assembly, att

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will display the contents of a txt file. I only have numbers stored in the new file, one number per line (%d \n). Currently the code looks like this:

```
movl $0 , 320(%ebp)
#a pre reserved location on the stack for the first number that needs to be cleared first  
leal 320(%ebp), %eax    #a pre-chosen location for the memory 
push %eax 
push $dataformat        # . asciz "%d \n"
push %ebx               #the result from the fopen is stored in ebx 
call _fscanf
push 320(%ebp)
push %dataformat
call _printf
```

However the result remains 0 unless I change the movl $0 to something else.

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: How to make it not print 0 but instead the required value.

Comment: Why are you calling `fscanf` twice, and not pushing the file handle the second time? Did you mean to call `printf`?

Comment: Yhea I manually typed that over since the computer it came from didn't have access to stack overflow

Comment: Are you positive that `ebx` contains a valid file handle by the time you push `ebx` on the stack? And also that the lines of the file _exactly_ match `"%d \n"` (maybe the line endings in your file differ slightly). You really should be checking the return values from the functions you call.

Comment: %eax apperently returns -1 that means it can't find the format right? Changing it into "%d" however did not fix the problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31517/discussion-between-thijser-and-michael)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved turned out the file in %ebx was in append mode not in write mode